# How to install valgrind properly?

Tags: linux, valgrind

I'm installing valgrind now, until the ‘make install’ command it goes good.
The next command- ‘make regtest’ outputs the next error:

```
../../depcomp: line 689: exec: g++: not found
make[5]: *** [leak_cpp_interior.o] Error 127
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/kbubuntu/valgrind-3.9.0/memcheck/tests'
make[4]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/kbubuntu/valgrind-3.9.0/memcheck/tests'
make[3]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/kbubuntu/valgrind-3.9.0/memcheck/tests'
make[2]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/kbubuntu/valgrind-3.9.0/memcheck'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kbubuntu/valgrind-3.9.0'
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: install g++ first. by typing sudo apt-get install g++.

Comment: Even if i work with gcc?

Comment: Anyway, they both already install.

Comment: then that should not happen

Comment: Why don't you just use the disto valgrind (`apt-get valgrind` or whatever)?  You don't have to build it.

Comment: but the thing is if g++ is already installed then why exec is showing error

Comment: are u sure g++ is already installed .. and but about installing build essedntials

Comment: @goldilocks this command output error: 'E: Invalid operation valgrind'

Comment: what !! what did you typed.. goldylocks was saying you to install valgring from apt-get..the command is sudo apt-get install velgrind.. but i have already checked there is no package in apt list named velgrind. either goldilocks did it from a ppa..

Comment: Whoops, my bad, sorry -- forgot `install`.  So `sudo apt-get install valgrind`.  I don't know which exact distro you are using but it should be there.  If not check: `sudo apt-cache search valgrind`.

Comment: I already done 'sudo apt-get install valgrind'. If so, that all? If yes, how can I use valgrind?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All major linux distributions will include valgrind in their repositories.  You can find this on debian derived, `apt` based systems with:

```
apt search valgrind
```

But first just try:

```
apt install valgrind
```

It should work, and pull in any dependencies.  Remember, if you are not the superuser, you'll need to preface those with `sudo`.

It's a great tool, have fun.

Comment: sir i just did it.. and it worked.. kindly tell me whose cache server it is using..

Comment: You mean `apt`?  That depends on your exact distro and how it is configured.  It's a separate question to this one though ;)  If you have an answer to your original question, tick one of the checkmarks to indicate this.

Comment: If you want to ask about `apt`, the Unix & Linux Exchange is a more appropriate place: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 51):

Short answer: Make from source.

How?

1. Uninstall the non working `valgrind` version with root rights (eg. `sudo`):

`apt-get --purge valgrind`
or
`dpkg --remove valgrind`
or
`yum remove valgrind`

2. Obtain sources from [here](http://valgrind.org/downloads/).
3. Identify the latest version (for example 3.17.0)
4. Download sources : `wget https://sourceware.org/pub/valgrind/valgrind-3.17.0.tar.bz2`
5. Decompress archive `tar xvf valgrind-3.17.0.tar.bz2`
6. Go to uncompressed archive `cd valgrind-3.17.0`
7. Configure `./configure`
8. Compile `make`
9. Install `make install` (with root rights, eg. `sudo`)

Note: very useful for Raspberry Pi 4 users - Default valgrind installation generate a lot of internal errors. See [Valgrind reports hundreds of errors in Hello World program on RaspberryPi 4B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59506152/valgrind-reports-hundreds-of-errors-in-hello-world-program-on-raspberrypi-4b)

Comment: For Dockerfile: # Valgrind!
# RUN apt-get install -y valgrind
ADD https://sourceware.org/pub/valgrind/valgrind-3.15.0.tar.bz2 /tmp/valgrind-3.15.0.tar.bz2
WORKDIR /src
RUN tar --strip-components=1 -x -f /tmp/valgrind-3.15.0.tar.bz2 \
&&  cd build \
&&  ../configure \
    --prefix=/opt/valgrind \
&&  make \
&&  make install \
&& rm -f /tmp/valgrind-3.15.0.tar.bz2
ENV VALGRIND_LIB /opt/valgrind/lib/valgrind
ENV PATH="/opt/valgrind/bin:${PATH}"

Answer (score 2):

i think its due to dependency not met.
install g++ 
by

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

then try again.
error is due to exec is unable to find any package named g++

Comment: if u can try installing build-essentials

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm still new at linux, how can i try that?

Comment: sudo apt-get install build-essential

Answer (score 0):

When trying to install Valgrind in Ubuntu 20.04, you can use apt or snap (notice the version number):

> :~/valgrind-3.18.1$ valgrind
>
> Command 'valgrind' not found, but can be installed with:
>
> sudo snap install valgrind  # version 3.18.1, or sudo apt  install
> valgrind  # version 1:3.15.0-1ubuntu9.1

Although snap provides the latest version, I preferred to install it natively by compiling the source code following the @g10guang instructions.