# How to install valgrind on linux

Tags: linux, valgrind

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs5tR.png)

I have basically tried every tutorial out there and still cant run valgrind.

So far....

I installed valgrind from their website to directory 'memcheck'

tar xvf valgrind-3.18.1.tar.bz2

the picture is the outcome of "./configure" ,I cant tell if it was successful or not.

then the command "make" gives: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
and the same for "make install"

this is what i tried to do. [How to install valgrind properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935217/how-to-install-valgrind-properly)

Comment: Have you checked whether your package manager can install it?

Comment: it can, but cant do the rest after that

Comment: Looks like you don't have `gcc` installed. Assuming you are on Ubuntu, have you tried `apt install valgrind`?

Comment: ok what after that?
and doesnt ubuntu have gcc already in it?

Comment: After that you may use Valgrind, if `apt` succeeded. Check the output of `which gcc` to find out if you have it.

Comment: "which gcc" gives no output

Comment: Than you should install it first. BTW: Why you need valgrind... more or less it is replaced by sanitizers which comes for free with your compiler

Answer (score 0):

If the output from `configure` contains "configure: error:" then it failed.

Installing with your package manager will be easiest.

Otherwise, you will need

A C compiler (e.g., gcc or clang), always.
GNU make, always.
Perl, probably always.
Sed and awk, always.

Autotools, m4, if regenerating the configure script.

Lots of packages if you want to generate the docs.

A C++ compiler (g++ or clang++) if you want to build and run the regression tests.

Comment: Thank you, my ubuntu didnt have gcc, g++ or cc.