# In aarch64 board valgrind doesn't give c++ file or function name where memory is lost

Tags: c++, valgrind, arm64

Valgrind reports memory definitely lost along with file and function names in x86 machine as expected.

```
  1 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
  2 
  3 using namespace std;
  4 int main()
  5 {
  6     char  *name = new char[30];
  7     cout << "Enter name" << endl;
  8     cin >> name;
  9     cout << "Hi " << name << endl;
 10   //delete name;
 11     return 0;
 12 }
```

**x86 machine**
uname -a:
`Linux raja-VirtualBox 5.4.0-135-generic #152~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 29 08:23:49 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`==8975== 30 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1`
`==8975==    at 0x4C3289F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)`
`==8975==    *`**`*by 0x1089CB: main (test.cpp:6)**`**
`==8975==`
`==8975== LEAK SUMMARY:`

But the same code when ran in an aarch64 machine, valgrind doesn't report any info like file or function name, though memory definitely lost is being reported.

**aarch64 board**
uname -a:
`Linux ds4 4.9.253-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 24 11:50:52 EST 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

`==19468== 30 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1`
`==19468==    at 0x48468F4: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so)`
`==19468==`
`==19468== LEAK SUMMARY:`

Anybody faced this in aarch64? How to get function, file names, line num.. in valgrind report for aarch64 or any such boards?

Note: valgrind and compiler versions are same in both x86 and aarch64.

Comment: Which version of valgrind are you using ? You might want to upgrade to the latest released version to get latest fixes.

Comment: valgrind --version
valgrind-3.13.0

Seems it is latest version because if I try to get upgrade:
valgrind is already the newest version (1:3.13.0-2ubuntu2.3).

Comment: Version 3.13 is more than 5 years old, which is really a lot in particular for aarch64. If your distribution is tool old and does not upgrade it, you should try to download from www.valgrind.org the last version and compile it yourself

Comment: Upgrading to latest valgrind version valgrind-3.20.0 resolved. 
Thanks @phd!

apt upgrade didn't work as I mentioned earlier, so downloaded valgrind 3.20.0 and compiled as you suggested which worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to latest valgrind version valgrind-3.20.0 resolved.
x86 gives debug info without valgrind upgrade, only aacrh64 requires upgrade.

Thanks @phd for your answer!!

PS: If someone facing "valgrind is already the newest version" due to your linux distribution and want's to manually download/compile valgrind you can refer:
[How to install valgrind properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935217/how-to-install-valgrind-properly)?